# Copy multiple structs data into one single C struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have multiple C structs of different datatypes as defined below

```
typedef struct Particle_1
 {
  char   name[16];
  int    lati_1;
  int    longi_1;
  float  pressure_1;
  double temperature_1;
 } Particle_1;

typedef struct Particle_2
 {
  char   name[16];
  int    longi_2;
  float  pressure_2;
  double temperature_2;
 } Particle_2;

typedef struct Particle
 {
  char   name[16];
  int    lati_1;
  int    longi_1;
  float  pressure_1;
  double temperature_1;
  char   name[16];
  int    longi_2;
  float  pressure_2;
  double temperature_2;
 } Particle;
```

Now whats the best way to copy data from the structs `Particle_1` and `Particle_2` to `Particle` without one to one variable assignment?
Furthermore, I dont want to define the struct `Particle` as struct of `Particle_1` and `Particle_2`

Comment: You have 2 members with the same name `name`. Do you want to keep both?

Comment: First, you need to define `struct location { int lat; int long; }` (although double seem more appropriate). Then get rid of the the typedefs.  And finally, get over your desire not to define `struct Particle { struct Particle_1; struct Particle_2;}`  Although since particle 2 seems to be a Particle 1 witout longitude, you might want to consider not even having a particle 2, but instead use a sentinel value (eg INT_MAX) in the  longitude field of particle 1 and then do `struct Particle { struct Particle_1[2]; }`

Comment: Have you considered a union of all the types?  Just change typedef struct to typedef union, then insert Particle_1 p1; Particle_2 p2;

Comment: Reddy2810,  Why the "I dont want to define the struct Particle as struct of Particle_1 and Particle_2" restriction?

Answer (score 2):

> Now whats the best way to copy data from the structs Particle_1 and Particle_2 to Particle without one to one variable assignment?

There is no conforming mechanism for doing this with the types as you have defined them.

> Furthermore, I dont want to define the struct Particle as struct of Particle_1 and Particle_2

This is, frankly, an absurd constraint.  You have one data structure that is a composite of the data of two others (and it's little more than a technicality that those are two rather than the same one), ***and*** you want interoperability among these.  The composite structure **should** have the other(s) as members:

```
struct particle {
    char   name[16];
    int    lati;
    int    longi;
    float  pressure;
    double temperature;
};

struct two_particles {
    struct particle p1;
    struct particle p2;
};
```

(Structure tags altered for clarity.)  Note that this requires only one single-particle structure, which I anticipate will also be an advantage, and you can use structure assignment to update one half and / or the other of a `struct two_particles`:

```
struct particle particle1 = /* ... */;
struct particle particle2 = /* ... */;
struct two_particles pair;

pair.p1 = particle1;
pair.p2 = particle2;
```

... or even ...

```
pair.p1 = pair.p2;
```

There is no aliasing between any of these, by the way.

In the event that you have existing code that depends on accessing the individual-particle members directly by decorated name, you could accommodate that, too, by incorporating some anonymous structures and unions:

```
struct two_particles_mix {
    union {
        struct particle p1;
        struct {
            char   name_1[16];
            int    lati_1;
            int    longi_1;
            float  pressure_1;
            double temperature_1;
        };
    };
    union {
        struct particle p2;
        struct {
            char   name_2[16];
            int    lati_2;
            int    longi_2;
            float  pressure_2;
            double temperature_2;
        };
    };
};
```

With that, you have both approaches in one:

```
struct two_particles_mix pair2;

pair2.p1 = particle1;
pair2.p2 = particle2;
int lati1 = pair2.lati_1;
double pressure2 = pair2.pressure_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

as @mch pointed out, you have two fields called `name` in Particle. Assumin that you are willing to rename the second to name_2, this ought to work. I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, so can't chek, but this will point you in the correct direction:

```
Particle_1 p1;
Particle_2 p2;
Particle_1 p;

memcpy(&p, &p1, sizeof(p1));
memcpy(&p.name_2, &p2, sizeof(p2));
```

Comment: Padding might be different between `Particle` and `Particle_2`.

Comment: A good point (+1), but doesn't that also affect your answer? ;-) The OP is being unrealistic, and `Particle` outght to contain either structures of, or pointers to structires of, `Particle_` and `Particle_2`

Comment: As is, a weak solution.  I see no portable good one now.  Going non-portable, make all 3 `struct`  _packed_.